# Spring MVC framework with Azure AD

Tags: spring, azure-active-directory

I am developing a web application using spring framework 5.2.8 (not spring boot) and spring security framework 5.2.5 with Azure AD. It seems a challenge as most examples in Microsoft's documentation use Spring boot.

I am unable to authenticate user using Azure AD. Has someone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no proper document about integrating Spring MVC framework with Azure AD.

You could authenticate user with [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) by sending a request to the `/token` Microsoft identity platform endpoint **or** using Integrated Windows Authentication like this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/tree/master/Integrated-Windows-Auth-Flow#invoking-an-api-protected-by-microsoft-identity-platform-with-users-signed-in-with-integrated-windows-authentication-on-a-windows-domain-joined-or-aad-joined-machine).